# Grab cell values from a table using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to grab the cell values from an HTML table generated from another PHP code. That I can use the result to send a rendezvous at final user.

My current [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g60ogt8c/1/) can grab some values but not like I want. I need to retrieve the attrib `title` & `value` from the button in the TD, my problem is currently the code return data from morning day and jump to the next morning day.

How I can return entire day `value` & `title` data's for each available days in the table ?

**Code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      

  eachCell();

  function eachCell(){
    var cellInnerText = [];
    var cellValue = [];
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    var out2 = document.getElementById("out2");
    $('#ft_agenda tbody tr').each(function(index) {        
        // console.log("index ", index, " this: " , this, "this.attr(rel)", $(this).attr('rel'), "$(this).text()", $(this).text());
        console.log($(":first-child", $(this))[0]);
        cellInnerText.push($("td button", $(this)).attr('value'));
        cellValue.push($("td button", $(this)).attr('title'));
    });
    out.innerHTML = cellInnerText.join(" | ");
    out2.innerHTML = cellValue.join(" | ");    
}

});
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with php?

Comment: Why don't you change your jquery to just search buttons `$('#ft_agenda tbody tr td button').each(function(index) {` and then you can get the value and title with `console.log($(this).attr('value')+' '+$(this).attr('title'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Try this code on your jsfiddle
// https://jsfiddle.net/g60ogt8c/1/
$(function() {

  function findColumnByDate(date) {
    var col;
    $('#ft_agenda thead th').each(function(idx) {
      if ($(this).text().trim() == date.trim()) col = idx;
    });
    return col;
  }

  function showAvailableTimes(date) {
    var times  = [],
        column = findColumnByDate(date);
    if (column) { 
      var $rows = $('#ft_agenda tbody td:nth-of-type('+column+')');
      if ($rows.length) {
        times[0] = '';
        $rows.find('button').each(function() { 
          times[times.length] = $(this).attr('value')+' - '+$(this).attr('title');
        });
        times[0] = 'For date '+date+' found '+(times.length-1)+' free terms';
      } else {
        times[0] = ['No free terms for date: '+date];
      }
    } else {
      times[0] = ['Invalid date '+date+' or date not found'];
    }
    return times;
  }

  // Function showAvailableTimes() now returns array.
  // In index 0 is status message and if available times found,
  // these lies on indexes 1 and more.

  // Use it this way:
  $('#out').html('');
  showAvailableTimes('15-09-2016').forEach(function(item) {
    $('#out').append(item + '<br>');
  });

  // Or this way:
  // Jsonify returned array and send it toSome.php.
  var json = JSON.stringify(showAvailableTimes('09-09-2016'));
  $.post('toSome.php', {times: json});

  // Or if there are free terms, filter status message
  // and send just free terms - without status message.
  var times = showAvailableTimes('09-09-2016');
  if (times.length > 1) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(times.filter(function(itm,idx){return idx>0}));
    $.post('toSome.php', {times: json});
    // Here you can see that status message was skipped
    $('#out2').text(json);
  }

});
```

Comment: Perfect WaldemarIce !! I will try to adapt it for my need. I mean customers give me their availability (ex : 15-09-2016) then I have to check if in the table the date match and finally return `value` + `title` Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe if you have some time or bored you can update your answer :)

Comment: Thanks dude, just check my first answer :)

Comment: So you need array or object of pairs value-title, not two independent arrays?

Comment: In my project i use the method ajax post to a php page and on success it return a echo of the table. Then with your code I compare if there is a match date available. Finally i do another ajax post to other php page with the data (value + title) to validate the rendez-vous. I hope that it's enough clear :)

Comment: Ok. And what enhancements exactly you need so my code will do differently/additionally/automatically?

Comment: For example costumers give me the date `15-09-2016` then i need to check if this date is available in the table and if it's the case, return the `value` + `title` of the the corresponding date.

Comment: Very impressive dude !! I need your skills :) Can i have your email for later help, please ?

Comment: No problem vladislav.ladicky@gmail.com